# Asp.net MVC, adding edmx gives trusted zone warning

Tags: asp.net-mvc, edmx, trusted

I have an ASP.net MVC 4 project I am working on and am trying to add an ADO.net EF model to it using Database First.

The creation of the model (.edmx file) seems to run successfully and I am left with the desired .edmx model file in the folder I specified. However, I don't appear to be able to see any of the files nested under this model. (From all my research, I should be able to expand the .edmx file and see *Context.vb, *Designer.vb, *.edmx.diagram and *.tt files underneath, but I cannot.)

It should look something like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx) in the msdn article about Database First (see Step 4):

Upon noticing this issue, I discovered a handful of warnings that appeared after creating the .edmx model, one of which is (I have obscured part of the full path):

***The path 'P:\IT\...\DAL\EF.Utility.VB.ttinclude' must be either local to this computer or part of your trusted zone. If you have downloaded this template, you may need to 'Unblock' it using the properties page for the template file in File Explorer.***

The project is stored on a network share on one of our servers so it can be included in our daily backups and Windows Shadow copy also. My understanding is that the above warning has appeared because of this and I need to set my machine to trust this location.

I have tried all possible variations I can think of of
[this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2bkwxc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
but to absolutely not success at all, the warning remains.

Either I am looking in the wrong place, or I have missed something.

Does anyone know what I can do to remove this warning and gain access to the objects nested below the .edmx model?

Comment: Looks similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208768/t4mvc-error-t4-file-is-blocked-or-in-a-non-trusted-zone

Comment: Sadly I saw this post and looked into this but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2bkwxc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) could be of some assistance.  I've never really dealt with trust issues working across the domain.  I lean towards pulling down and working with a local copy.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately however, that link is the exact one I mention in my question and hasn't helped me a great deal :(