# T4 Code Generation Mystery (Win8.1 in Parallels VM)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, virtual-machine, code-generation, t4, parallels

T4 appears to run successfully but generates no files!  It works on my Win 7 PC and for all other developers on my team, so I think it's an environment issue.

The T4 code generation script runs without an error and I have the T4 toolbox for Visual Studio 2013 Community installed.  At first I ran into an error where T4 said my folders were not "trusted" but I fixed this by adding the folder "file://psf" (parallels vm shared folder) to IE's Trusted site zone.

Any ideas??

Comment: I realize this is a painful one to troubleshoot - hence why no one is tackling it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [T4MVC Error - T4 file is blocked or in a non trusted zone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208768/t4mvc-error-t4-file-is-blocked-or-in-a-non-trusted-zone)

Comment: @Mitch, I had tried several of the solutions from that question but nothing worked... in the end I re-mapped my project to a folder that wasn't shared and the code-gen worked at that point.

Comment: The issue is almost unquestionably CAS.  I would double-check to make sure the `\\psf` is properly identified.  See also: `caspol` and https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Caspol-f2c61fb1